# mclapply() instead of nested for loops

Tags: r, nested-loops, lapply, mclapply

I have a huge matrix and would like to calculate the distance matrix using pairwise comparison of all columns. I know that built in dist() functioin in R already does the job but I would like to do this manually using nested for loops. I have written the following code which returns the matrix as desired.

The issue is that my real data is huge and nested for loops takes forever to compute the dist matrix.

```
mtx <- matrix(rnorm(20), nrow = 4, ncol = 5)
mtx.out <- matrix(0, nrow = 5,  ncol = 5)

for(i in 1:ncol(mtx)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(mtx)){
    mtx.out[i,j] <- sqrt(sum((mtx[[i]] - mtx[[j]]) ^ 2))
  }
}
```

I was wondering how I can use lapply or mclapply and specify the number of cores on my computer to make the process faster.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a compelling reason not to use `dist()` which is optimized for this purpose? It  saves you from making the errors in computation that are present in your code. mtx[[i]] is not the same as mtx[, 1] so your distances are all wrong. Compare your results to `dist(t(mtx), diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE)`.

Comment: Hi, yes. Indeed I need to calculate distance matrix using another method. I just used the formula of euclidean distance in my code to have a fair explanation of my problem.  The structure of my input is as I explained So I need a nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to compute the distances directly, this will be faster than the double loop, partly because it does not compute the distances twice (1 vs 2 and 2 vs 1) and it does not compute distances of a column with itself (1 vs 1):

```
set.seed(42)    $ Make the example reproducible
mtx <- matrix(rnorm(20), nrow = 4, ncol = 5)

dmat <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
dsts <- apply(combn(1:5, 2), 2, function(x) sqrt(sum((mtx[, x[1]] - mtx[, x[2]])^2)))
dmat[lower.tri(dmat)] <- dsts
dmat[upper.tri(dmat)] <- dsts
dmat
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
# [1,] 0.000000 1.729993 2.071973 3.930348 4.959642
# [2,] 1.729993 0.000000 2.818655 2.884562 4.055794
# [3,] 2.071973 2.884562 0.000000 2.546453 5.195339
# [4,] 2.818655 2.546453 4.055794 0.000000 3.558716
# [5,] 3.930348 4.959642 5.195339 3.558716 0.000000
# 
dist(t(mtx), diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE)   # Using the dist() function
#          1        2        3        4        5
# 1 0.000000 1.729993 2.071973 2.818655 3.930348
# 2 1.729993 0.000000 2.884562 2.546453 4.959642
# 3 2.071973 2.884562 0.000000 4.055794 5.195339
# 4 2.818655 2.546453 4.055794 0.000000 3.558716
# 5 3.930348 4.959642 5.195339 3.558716 0.000000
```

In contrast, your code produces:

```
mtx.out
#           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
# [1,] 0.0000000 1.9356566 1.00783004 0.7380958 0.96669012
# [2,] 1.9356566 0.0000000 0.92782658 1.1975608 0.96896649
# [3,] 1.0078300 0.9278266 0.00000000 0.2697342 0.04113991
# [4,] 0.7380958 1.1975608 0.26973419 0.0000000 0.22859428
# [5,] 0.9666901 0.9689665 0.04113991 0.2285943 0.00000000
```

Comment: Hi, actually I want to use another function that takes the values of pair of columns as input and returns a number.  So I want to pass all pairs of columns and store the output in a matrix. My function is just similar to dist() function, that is why that I mentioned it as example here.